# Can protagonist be an antagonist, and vise versa?

Tags: word-usage, differences, terminology, story

The protagonist, is the main actor, no matter what his character is--good or bad. Normally, it centralized the story with the protagonist.

On the other hand, the antagonist is the opposing character of the protagonist, with conflicting characteristics with the protagonist.

What if the protagonist and antagonist change roles? Is there any special term for that? Like when either the protagonist and antagonist lead the story, having different plots, and both have the part in causing the trouble. Some stories use an interrelated parallel story plot that helps one another develop each plot.

So, back to the question, how do you call that instances? How if the protagonist act as the antagonist, and vise verse for the antagonist? What's your idea about this?

Comment: I'm sure that there have been books written where the (initial) protagonist and antagonist switched roles.

Comment: You'd probably get better answers over at [Literature.SE]. This really isn't a question about language but about plot and character.

Comment: @Mitch: Exactly the same question was asked here 12 years ago, and it's marked as a  [***Highly active question***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85336/can-the-protagonist-be-the-antagonist), so arguably this *must* be the right place for it!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't vote to close. I'm just pointing out that, whatever English labels are applied to these concepts, people who are more conversant with such concepts are probably more active over at [writers.SE] or [Literature.SE]. If the question was 'What is a word for such a character?'  and 'What variety of English was Aristotle speaking when he invented these terms?' then that'd be unquestionably on-topic here.

Comment: Well, for me it was a toss-up between POB and DUP - which I knew *did* exist, so it was just a matter of tracking it down. In the event, a site-specific Google search for **protagonist antagonist** easily picked it out.When I tried again just now with just the ***first*** word, top of the list was [this closed question,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/493532/) asking *Is a 'Protagonist' really a thing or is it a misnomer derived from it's opposite 'Antagonist'?* Which may or may not be useful for the OP here.